# В матрице надо поменять местами столбцы с минимальным и максимальным значениями

Tags: java

То есть, есть столбец с максимальным элементом матрицы и его надо поменять со столбцом, который содержит минимальный элемент матрицы.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Я вообще не понимаю, как это сделать. Я только вывела на экран начальную матрицу, а дальше как делать не знаю.

```
// часть 1 - создаем матрицу n на n
        int n;
        Scanner con = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите количество строк и стобцов n = ");
        n = con.nextInt();
        if (n<=0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array is empty!");
        }
        if (n==1){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("It's not suitable for this assignment!");
        }
        int[][] a = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                a[i][j] = n*i + j;//a[i][j] = n*i + j " просто заполняет массив по порядку числами , начиная с 0
            }
        }
// часть 2 - выводит на экран начальную матрицу
        System.out.println("Начальная матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", a[i][j]);//"%4d" значит "4 пробела"
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Для начала нужно найти минимальный и максимальный элемент матрицы и запомнить индексы их столбцов

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это сделать. Для массива знаю, но для матрицы нет.

Comment: Матрица есть, размер её известен. Значит нужно сделать внутренний цикл перебора строк, вложенный в наружный цикл перебора столбцов. Будет похоже на одномерный массив, но индексов будет не один, а два, поэтому и циклов нужно тоже два - внешний и внутри него ещё один.